# Qualifying as a realtor to save on commission

Tags: united-states, real-estate, career

My wife and I are thinking about selling our home and are very upset about the prospect of losing 6%+ of our home value on commission. We live in Texas.

We both have careers that are unrelated to real estate but we love and understand a little bit of the real estate market. From what I understand, in the USA it is not mandatory to use a realtor for selling your home, but obviously we would be super cautious about it.

With that in mind, and considering we want to do real estate in the long term, is it possible, does it make sense, and what are the potential risks of either getting a realtor license or simply watching all the real estate school courses (without getting a license) in order to save on that commission in the long run and deal with all the businesses ourselves?

Comment: "in the USA it is not mandatory to use a realtor for selling your home"—as I understand it, it varies by state. Some may not require any particular intermediary, some require a realtor, and some require a lawyer.

Comment: Doing real estate long term and saving on the commission for the sale of your current house are two different issues. I don't know a thing about the profession of RE but  I've sold a couple of houses without using a realtor.  In one case I  took 20% down with a 5 year balloon payment. In each case, I used a lawyer to review the contracts that the buyer and I drew up.  Maybe that cost $100-$200.  The only other major fee was the title company and that was $500 or so.  In all cases, I reduced the comp prices by 2% or so and held fast. Saved almost 4%.